# Dropdownlist in masterpage is not returning a default value that was set by content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown, master-pages

I have a DropDown bound to a data source. And has auto-postback to true so that I can call middle-tier based on the value selected. But, by default, the second value in the dropdown is selected by the content page in the page load event. But a method on the content page doesn't get the selected value.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatuses" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsStatus" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="false" Visible="false"
    DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="StatusId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatuses_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In master page code-behind, I have the following methods to get, set the status.

```
public delegate void StatusHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        
public partial class MasterPageTest: System.Web.UI.MasterPage    
{
    public event StatusHandler StatusChanged;    
    
    protected virtual void OnStatusChanged(EventArgs e)
    {}
    
    public int SelectedStatus()
    {
        return ddlStatuses.SelectedValue.ToInt();
    }
    
    public bool ShowStatusDDL
    {
        get { return ddlStatuses.Visible; }
        set { ddlStatuses.Enabled = ddlStatuses.Visible = value; }
    }
    
    public void SetSelectedStatusDDL()
    {
        ddlStatuses.SelectedValue = Statuses.Unread.ToString();
    }
    
    protected void ddlStatuses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (StatusChanged != null)
        {
            StatusChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

The content page sets the default Status in the dropdown on page load and then try to call a method to pass the selected value to middle tier. This is where the problem is - on load it doesn't get the default value, but on dropdown change, it works as expected.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Master.StatusChanged += Master_StatusChanged;

if(!IsPostBack) {        
    Master.ShowStatusDDL = true;
    Master.SetSelectedStatusDDL(); //Setting the status to say 2nd item in the list

    MainFunctionality();
}

private void MainFunctionality()
{
    var statusId = Master.SelectedStatus();   // This doesn't show the selected status but blank
    //Some more code that passes the statusId to the middle tier
}
```

Why won't it get the default value, I am sure there is something silly that I am not seeing. But, I already spent hours in it to debug.

Here is a little more background:
Originally, I had an `ObjectDataSource` in content page aspx that loads the results in the `GridView`, and the following event `dsMessages_Selecting` reads the `Master.SelectedStatus()` to pass it to the data source to get the filtered data. And this event was able to read the selected dropdown value. I removed that object data source to write my own in the code behind on page load. Now, the selected dropdown doesn't work. Although content page load sets the default value, but there is some other event that I am missing that makes sure the value is selected.

Comment: The Master page's Page_load gets executed after the content page's Page_load. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Master page's page_load has no code for me, and I set the value in the content page_load. I am sure that it is something to do with the event life cycle, but not able to pinpoint it yet. I have updated the OP with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, for other's who might get into this issue in the future and spend a lot of time understanding the problem, I am posting the solution.

The issue was with the way events were firing, thanks to `@VDWWD` for making me think about how events are getting fired.

I had a code in the content page_load event that was setting the dropdown default selection and followed it with the code that would load the grid using the selected value.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Master.StatusChanged += Master_StatusChanged;

    if(!IsPostBack) {        
        Master.ShowStatusDDL = true;
        Master.SetSelectedStatusDDL(); //Setting the status to say 2nd item in the list

        MainFunctionality();
    }
}
```

This grid was not filtering the data based on the selection, because the content `page_load` didn't know about the selection somehow, I would assume that gets updated later in the event lifecycle.

So I moved that MainFunctionality() from content `page_load` to content `gridview_PreRender` to delay the call to find the selected dropdown value. Since this is almost the last event that fires before the unload event, I thought by then I will get the selected dropdown value. And, it worked exactly how I wanted it to work.

The following is the sequence in which events occur when a master page is merged with a content page for your reference:

Content page PreInit event.

Master page controls Init event.

Content controls Init event.

Master page Init event.

Content page Init event.

Content page Load event.

Master page Load event.

Master page controls Load event.

Content page controls Load event.

Content page PreRender event.

Master page PreRender event.

Master page controls PreRender event.

Content page controls PreRender event.

Master page controls Unload event.

Content page controls Unload event.

Master page Unload event.

Content page Unload event.

[From Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dct97kc3(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)